# HTML Login to another site by clicking a reference

Tags: html, get

I have been using the post method to login a “Guest” user to another site, like in the following:

```
<form action="http://example.com/login.asp" method="post" target="_blank">
<input type="hidden" name="username" value="Guest" />
<input type="hidden" name="password" value="0000"/>
<input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

I need now to avoid this method and I wish to use the get method instead, like in the following:

```
<a href="http://example.com/login.asp?username=Guest&password=0000" target="_blank">Login as Guest</a>
```

I reach the page and the username and password values are on, but I cannot find what is missing to achieve the login without the need of clicking a button by the user. In other words, the user by clicking the link should be logged in with no further action. Is there any way?

Please advice.

Comment: It depends on how the validation happens on back end. If it is expecting POST request and you are sending GET , it will not work. Showing your validation code might be helpfull

Comment: Just keep in mind that is never really a good idea to send log in information using GET because it is visible in the URL for all to see.

Comment: This particular login information is not "sensitive" as the "Guest" user has limitations. The validation code you are mentioning belongs to the site I try to login the Guest (I cannot provide it but through firefox I have seen that it expects (params) a value "login" for its button "btnSubmit"). Please note that the post method I show, works OK as I have included the aforementioned input. It seems to me that the only thing I miss from the anchor link is the action that triggers the login. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

in http://example.com/login.asp at beginning just check username and password is present or not and all others what you want and then logged them in and finaly one thing when you using form then your method is **POST** but when you go through anchor link then method is **GET** it's not **POST** and I think you miss this..

Comment: The way I write the anchor link is a GET, isn't it? If you think I miss something please explain. Perhaps what I miss from the anchor link is the action that triggers the login, as the other site is expecting a value "login" for its button "btnSubmit". Thank you!

Comment: request.querystring("username") or request.form("username") which one you use ?

Comment: I do not need to find the values because the values are fixed: username=Guest - password=0000, I only need to submit them through the anchor link (to login to the other site) without the form of a button (NOT like <input ... />), if there is any way. What I need is an HTML solution - nothing with asp. Asp belongs to the other site where I wish to login the user (any user) with generic username=Guest and generic password=0000 (anyone may login manually with the aforementioned username and password as they are not secret).

Comment: How would you know some one came on your login.asp page from demo login link without checking that ....
<code>
If request.querystring("username") 
//then login them as demo user where username = Guest and password=0000
</code>

please provide your login.asp page

Comment: The login.asp page is not on my application. My application uses just html. Imagine that you call from your browser the http://example.com/login.asp page and you are shown two input boxes for username and password. Then you plug in "Guest" for username and "0000" for password and you are logged in. I just want to feed those two input boxes through my html. My anchor calls and feeds correctly the login.asp page but I have to click the button "btnSubmit" of that login.asp page which doesn't belong to my application. So I wish to complete my anchor link with something that "clicks" that button.

Comment: ok so login.asp is not your application . You can do it through cURL

Comment: Following your suggestion, I made a lot of reading for cURL, but still I cannot figure out how to use it in my anchor tag or anyhow in the body of my html. Could you please show me how to do it in the context of my question to stackoverflow? In any way, I really thank you for your effort to help me.